# Android Asynctask post to server error

Tags: android

Am new to android and developing an android app that posts a search item (which is supplied by user  into an EditText) to the server when a button is clicked,the item is posted to the server.Am using Asynctask class.I have error with the findViewById(it is undefined).My problem is where to place the onclick method and referncing of the views.Here is the code

```
public class Server_Post extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
    private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
    private final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
      HttpResponse response;

      Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
      EditText textvalue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searcheditText);

      //Onclick Listener
      Submit.setOnClickListener(onClickListener) 
      private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(final View v) {
              switch(v.getId()){
                  case R.id.submitButton:
                break;
          }
      };

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    //any code    

    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String URL = "url";
    String username = "abc";
    String password = "xyz";


    try {
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

        //Any other parameters you would like to set
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 

        //Response from the Http Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        //Check the Http Request for success
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();

        }
        else{
            //Closes the connection.
            Log.w("HTTP1:",statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;


}

protected void onCancelled() {

}

protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

}


private void connecttopostdata() {  
    Server_Post task = new Server_Post();  
    task.execute(textvalue.getText().toString());  
  }

 }
```

the response is in xml and i want to also dispaly the response on listviews.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a context of an activity class to get button from findviewbyid . Make a constructor and find your views from there. Like..

```
// give context from where you are calling your AsyncTask
 public Server_Post (Context context)
{
    Button Submit = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    EditText textvalue = (EditText)context.findViewById(R.id.searcheditText);
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, but IMO the logic for getting the data should be completely separated and in a different class, and the data passed in using the args in the `onPreExecute` method